# Contact Form 7 - Check certain number in text field

Tags: wordpress, forms, validation

sorry for my english. I will do my best.

I´m planning to build a text field in CF7 as "simple" captcha field. I use a text field and Ißm planning to check if the value is right.

For example:
How many legs has a dog?

The right answer is 4. So only the digit 4 is valid in the text field. In other case, a text line will widplay under the field like: Sorry, thats wrong.

How can I build this in cf7. Is it possible with text or number field and how?

br
janwill

Comment: This is how - https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/

Comment: Welcome! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this line:

```
 $value = preg_match( '/^\d{1}$/', $plz);
```

This line checks, if the value is 1, but how can I also check, if it's number 4?
Found [here](https://torstenlandsiedel.de/2018/06/17/custom-validation-fuer-postleitzahlen-bei-contact-form-7/).

Maybe like this?

```
$value = preg_match( '/(^|[^A-Za-z0-9])4([^A-Za-z0-9]|$)/i', $plz);
```